# What does “akin to” mean in etymologies in dictionary entries?

Tags: meaning, etymology, terminology, dictionaries

Many etymologies in dictionaries say that some word is “akin to” a word in some other language. For example, here is part of the [*Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary* entry for *salt*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/salt):

> Main Entry: **<sup>1</sup>salt**
>
> Etymology: Middle English, from Old English *sealt;* akin to Old High German *salz* salt, Lithuanian *saldus* sweet, Latin *sal* salt, Greek *hals* salt, sea

It says that *salt* is “akin to” words in Old High German, Lithuanian, Latin, and Greek. What does that mean? Does it mean that the word is borrowed from those languages? How could a word be borrowed from more than one language?

Comment: I’ve added a bounty to this question because none of the answers so far is really right. The right answer will address types of relationships between languages and the difference between borrowing and inheriting words.

Comment: @cindi is exactly right: words that are *akin* share genetic material; i.e. they derive from the same root in a common ancestor language.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First, a brief lesson in historical linguistics. Language families arose at some point in the past from what linguists call proto-languages, which is a term that refers to a language that is reconstructed rather than one that is attested. There is debate over whether language families all derive back to a single proto-language or if several proto-languages developed independently. In either case, as the group forming the speakers of a proto-language grows over time, it eventually splits into two or more separate groups whose language started out the same and then over time became mutually unintelligible. Those two “child” languages are related in the family tree of languages. The child languages can then grow and split as well. In the history of English, there have been several splits, but two are significant: first, the proto-Indo-European language split into various languages forming the subfamilies of Indo-European, such as the Germanic languages (proto-Germanic) and the Romance languages (Latin). The Germanic languages also split, eventually resulting in English being a separate language from the other Germanic languages, such as German, Swedish, and Dutch.

A word becomes part of a language in two ways: (1) it inherits them from ancestor languages; (2) they borrow them from contemporary foreign languages. For example, the English word *brother* derives in a direct lineage back through proto-Germanic to the proto-Indo-European root **bʰréh₂tēr*. This is an inherited word. The other way a word enters a language is to be borrowed from a contemporary foreign language. This is like the English word *croissant* which was borrowed from the French word *croissant*. That is, when the word *croissant* became a part of English, it was copied from people who were speaking a foreign language—French. Even though French and English are related—both being Indo-European languages—the word *croissant* was borrowed from French because the word entered English after French speakers and English speakers split apart long enough for their languages to be mutually unintelligible.

Now, French also has a word for *brother* that derives from the proto-Indo-European root **bʰréh₂tēr*: that French word is *frère*. This is where the word *akin* comes in. The English word *brother* is **akin** to the French word *frère* because both languages inherited those words from their ancestor languages, and they both ultimately derive from the same root in their closest common ancestor language, proto-Indo-European.

So, when a dictionary etymology says “word A in language L1 is **akin to** word B in language L2”, that means that neither word A nor word B were borrowed into their respective language and both word A and word B derive from the same root word in L1 and L2’s common ancestor language. That is, when *Merriam-Webster* say about *salt* that it is “akin to Old High German *salz* salt, Lithuanian *saldus* sweet, Latin *sal* salt, Greek *hals* salt, sea” they mean that the English word *salt* and those other words from related languages all come from the same root in their common ancestor language, proto-Indo-European.

A couple of other terms you might find:

- **derivative**: a derivative is a word that is derived from a root word. Both *brother* and *frère* are derivates of **bʰréh₂tēr*.
- **reflex**: a reflex is a sound in a descendent language that corresponds to a sound in the ancestor language. For example, the proto-Indo-European sound /bʰ/ has the reflex sound /b/ in English and /f/ in French, which is why the English derivative is *brother* and the French derivative is *frère*. Similarly, the proto-Indo-European root **bʰudʰ-no-* has derivative *bottom* in English and *fond* in French, and **bʰerǵʰ-* meaning “fort” has derivatives *burg* and *borough* in English and *fort* in French. (The English word *fort* was borrowed later from French).

Comment: +1 nice answer :). Is it worth mentioning that the phrase "akin to" (outside of linguistics) simply means "related to"?

Comment: @nohat, Btw is there any linked sources/citations for this answer?

Answer (score 9):

When they indicate that a word comes from a language, it indicates a direct, known relationship between the two words. When they switch to saying "akin to," the entry indicates that there is likely an indirect relationship between the word in question and the word it is akin to.

A quick lookup indicates that English originated from a West German dialect, which I'm sure relates to Old High German in some manner. Going to the example in *salt*, the entry indicates that there is the Old English word and the Old High German word. However, there's at least one language in between those two that the etymology flows through. Since the Old High German is only akin to the Old English, all the ancestor words from the Old High German are also akin to the present-day word.

In short, there's a missing link in the etymological chain. The term "akin to" recognizes that fact.

Comment: just curious, could you post the citation from the quick look up? i wasn't expecting an answer like yours at all but you've piqued my interest

Comment: What time frame did this West Germanic dialect coin this word?

Comment: @mfg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language

@itrekkie I'm not familiar with the timeline over which this evolution of language occurred

Answer (score 3):

From the *NOAD*:

> akin /əˈkɪn/
>   adjective
>   of similar character: *something akin to gratitude overwhelmed her* | *genius and madness are akin*.
>   • related by blood.
>   ORIGIN middle 16th century: contracted form of *of kin*.

In the case of words, it means there is a similarity between the words, or they have a common (or shared) root.

Reading what the *NOAD* says about *salt*, I find:

> ORIGIN
>   Old English *sealt* (noun), *sealtan* (verb), of Germanic origin; related to Dutch *zout* and German *Salz* (nouns), from an Indo-European root shared by Latin *sal*, Greek *hals* 'salt'.

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* uses *related to* where the *Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary* uses *akin to*.

Answer (score 2):

That word is so close to another word in another language they are practically family.  They may share a common ancestor word or just sound so alike that a relationship is imagined.

Comment: No respectable etymological dictionary would list words that "just sound so alike that a relationship is imagined" (except to point out that they were false cognates, perhaps).

Answer (score 2):

*Akin* simply means *similar to*.

Comment: Couldn't agree more! "Akin" does not, as the questioner suggests, have any connotation of one word being borrowed from another language.

Comment: Indeed, “akin to” has a specific meaning concerning language family relationships.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the M-W dictionary, I noticed that they have both “from” and “akin to” references for words.

The “from” references seem to imply a direct inheritance or borrowing, but doesn't distinguish between the two.  For instance, *[stone](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stone)* is shown as coming from Middle English *stān*, while *[entrée](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entree)* is shown as coming from the French *entrée*.  The former is an inheritance from Old English, while the latter is a direct borrow from French.

“Akin to”, however, seems to refer to other languages that have similar words, possibly due to a shared past, possibly due to an origin not definitively proven.  M-W does not seem to specify this, but when drawing links between languages as diverse as Slavic, Germanic, and Greek languages, it's arguable that a common ancestry is implied rather than a direct inheritance or borrowing relationship.  However, looking up words like *banana* or *yam*, they use “from” to show the direct relation to Spanish or Portuguese and say “of African origin”, but “akin to” to describe the most likely African language source.

In short, for the M-W team at least, “from” seems to mean "we know where it came from and we can prove it", while “akin to” seems to mean "these words sure seem related, but we can't prove exactly how they're tied together."

Answer (score 1):

i forget the word for when two words are pushed together to make one, but it means they are "kin" ([def "1. a person's relatives collectively; kinfolk. 2. family relationship or kinship](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kin)". The prefix "a-" being akin to its usage in awash, etc.

Comment: The bit about "family roots" or kinship set a little light bulb off in my head–quite charming, actually. Thanks for the more detailed semantic info!