# English from Icelandic?

Tags: etymology, germanic-languages, loanwords

Why is it that so many English words, as one traces their etymologies, run through Icelandic as one goes back?

Comment: Can you give an example of a word whose etymology runs through Icelandic?

Comment: @nohat [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icelandic_language#Cognates_with_English) gives several: _epli_, _bók_, _hár_, _hús_, _móðir_, _nótt_, _steinn_, _það_, _orð_, which are all nearly identical to their English counterparts (if you are familiar with the Icelandic alphabet).

Comment: I believe it is more a case of having a common Germanic root rather than 'running through' Icelandic.

Comment: @Shane: Icelandic and English do have Germanic as a common ancestor but there was also lateral transfer of words from the higher common denominator Old Norse.

Comment: @HaL none of those words are English words

Comment: @nohat, I think they need translation.

Comment: As others have noted, there don't seem to be many English words that do derive directly from Icelandic. There are quite a few that come from a common earlier root, but that's a different question.

Comment: @nohat @Third _apple, book, hair, house, mother, night, stone, that, word_

Comment: @HaL — what Hugo said. See my answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/what-does-akin-to-mean-in-etymologies-in-dictionary-entries/3582#3582) for an explanation of how to understand etymologies.

Comment: @nohat I read through your original comment too quickly. Those words are just cognates, not etymological derivatives. As Shane said, they probably share a Germanic root.

Comment: @HaL yes, exactly right. In fact, they don’t just *probably* share a Germanic root, they *necessarily* do—that’s what makes them cognates.

Answer (score 15):

English doesn't have many words which come from Icelandic, ***[geyser](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/geyser)*** and ***[saga](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saga)*** are possibly the most prominent.

But English does have a good few words which share a common ancestor with Icelandic. Icelandic as the most conservative of the Scandinavian languages is relatively close to Old Norse, from which English borrowed while the vikings were in Britain. They include such seemingly native words as ***[them](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=them)***, ***[skirt](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skirt)***, and ***[sky](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sky)***.

Then, of course, English is actually related to Old Norse and Icelandic since they are all Germanic languages. This is where most of the similar words in English and Icelandic mentioned in other comments and answer really come from.

So broadly speaking there are three kinds of related words between English and Icelandic: Directly borrowed, via Old Norse, and descended from [proto-Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language).

Comment: And more commonplace examples would be "them", "skirt" and "sky".

Comment: @Colin: I tried to pick one that was still spelled the same in Icelandic and English and felt Icelandic too. Also I was too lazy to dig through lots of etymologies (-:

Comment: Fine. But my point is that "saga" is a comparatively modern loan, and still feels like one ("-a" is extremely rare in native English words), whereas I was exemplifying Norse loanwords that entered the language so long ago that they are naturalised.

Comment: @Colin: Oh I didn't realise *saga* was borrowed 300 years ago - you're right. I was originally thinking about one of the pronounds/demonstratives in *th-* but thought I'd struck gold with saga. I'll look into it a bit more and edit my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think it's what I know as **red car syndrome**, which urban dictionary calls [blue car syndrome](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Blue%20Car%20Syndrome)

Either you know Icelandic, or you recently noticed one Icelandic etymology in particular, and thereafter became particularly prone to notice others.

Answer (score -1):

English was heavily influenced by the old norse language, and icelandic hasn't changed much from old norse over time so it's still very close to it.

Now I don't speak icelandic, but I speak swedish, which also comes from old norse, and even between swedish and english there are a lot of similarities.

Some examples of english-icelandic words that both come from old norse:
Father - Faðir (fathir, roughly..)
Mother - móðir (mothir, also roughly..)
House - hús
Knife - hnífur (both come from the old norse word hníf)
Window - vindauga (both come from old norse and literally mean 'an eye towards the wind')

So.. yeah, hope that was helpfull.

Comment: Of the words you list, only _window_ is from Old Norse. The rest are all native English words.