# Words that originate from Icelandic

Tags: etymology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [English from Icelandic?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27270/english-from-icelandic)

Are there any English words that are of a common or semi-common use that originate from Icelandic?

Comment: Without a specific context, your question is very broad. Do you have a specific situation, or are you just compiling a list?

Comment: I am compiling a list, but I am mostly just curious.

Comment: bjork - a strange background noise

Comment: I doubt any - a handful at most - originate from Icelandic. A fair few originate from Old Norse of course, which shares a lot in common with Icelandic... I see no historical reason why Icelandic should have had any influence on our language though.

Comment: Interesting. The question this was closed in favor of was essentially an incorrect (as phrased) question. Its accepted answer is a good answer for this one though. Since this is a better question, but that has better answers, I'd rather see that question's answers **merged** into this question. Voting to reopen for that reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are of course many English words borrowed into late Old English and early Middle English from Old West and Old East Scandinavian, the former being the ancestor of modern Icelandic, but English has borrowed very few words from medieval or modern Icelandic. The only one that comes to mind just now is *geyser*, a late 18th century borrowing of Icelandic [*Geysir*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geysir), which is the name of a particular hot spring in southwest Iceland; the name derives from the Old Norse verb *geysa* 'to send out with violence'.

There are a few terms that were borrowed into English in Early Modern times or later that could in principle have been borrowed from contemporary Icelandic but in fact were not: rather, they were borrowed from literary Old Norse. Some examples are *saga* (early 18th century), *viking* (19th century), and *Ragnarok* (late 18th century). As these examples suggest, such words are generally associated with early Scandinavian literature and mythology. Other relatively late borrowings that at first sight might appear to be from Icelandic, like *troll* (Icelandic *tröll* 'giant') and *fjord* (Icelandic *fjörður*, in which *-ur* is an inflexional ending), actually entered English via the Continental Scandinavian languages.

Despite the traditionally conservative Icelandic language policy and the unusually widespread linguistic purism in Iceland, there are actually many more Icelandic borrowings from modern English; [this paper](http://ojs.ub.gu.se/ojs/index.php/njes/article/viewFile/257/254) by Guðrún Kvaran has a nice (and quite readable) discussion of them.

(Dates are mostly from [the Online Etymological Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php).)

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize any word from these two lists as having made it into English on any frequent basis:

https://wiki.familysearch.org/en/Icelandic_Word_List

http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/1995/of95-807/geoicelandic.html (Geoscience terms--I thought that, given Iceland's remarkable geology, some borrowing might have occurred, but apparently borrowings occurred from common European roots, not directly.)

(For what it's worth, I once sat next to two Icelandic speakers on a plane for hours without being able to figure out which language they were speaking. Finally had to ask out of sheer curiosity!)

Comment: Supposedly saga and geyser - although both could be from any Norse root

Answer (score 0):

Geyser, comes from Geysir, the name of one in Iceland.

Comment: Do you have sources to back this up?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/geyser was linked to in the answer to the "duplicate" question.